# How I remove unwanted pre and code tags of html content with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I created this based code, but how I remove all pre and code tags.

```
private static string RemoveHtmlTags(this string markup)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(markup))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var document = new HtmlDocument();

    document.LoadHtml(markup);

    return document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Do you want them stripped entirely (including their contents) or just have their contents unwrapped and just remove the tags themselves?

Comment: Remove tag with content.